# How to control url in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, routes, url-routing

I use the default LogOn model of MVC3. LogOn partial view is in Layout view.

```
@Html.Partial( "~/Views/Home/LogOn.cshtml", new MyProject.Models.LogOnModel() )
```

After log on, Url is:

```
http://localhost:20234/?UserName=TestUsername&Password=121212&RememberMe=True
```

I dont want the password seen in the URL.
How do I remove the password (also Username, RememberMe) from the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you transfer data to server with GET method then parameters are visible in url. You should use POST method in this case. For example:

```
<form action="/Account/Logon" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Username"/>
    <input type="text" name="Password"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I wrote : @using ( Html.BeginForm( "LogOn", "Home", FormMethod.Post ))
{....}  in LogOn partial view

Comment: Yes, that will render as: <form action="/Home/LogOn" method="POST">...</form> Now you should post a form and that's it.

Comment: You are posting with <input type=submit/> ? you should not use <a href="..."></a> to post a form.

Comment: I am posting with <input type=submit/>

Answer (score 1):

1)Pease change to your default route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                    "DefaultSite",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new
                        { 
                            controller ="Account",
                            action ="LogOn",
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional
                        }
                    );
```

2)Load partial on Master Load file:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn","Account",HttpMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
        @Html.Partial( "~/Views/Home/LogOn.cshtml", new MyProject.Models.LogOnModel())          
    }
```

3)And Account contrroller in added your logon logice:

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //TODO:

                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", @"The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: LogOn is partial view in my application and place in Home view.